# Windows API: write to screen as on screen display

Tags: windows, winapi, screen

I am writing a (very) small application which just performs some minor things at start and should write a message on the screen similar as for an on-screen-display: Big letters, without any window, above everything, visible for some moment and then fade away.

If possible I do not want to create a window for it.

What is the right way to do this?

(I hope there are no special toolkits like DirectX, direct graphics access etc. required)

Comment: Creating a window would be the normal way to do this. Windows can be transparent and don't need to have a visible frame etc, if that's what's putting you off using one.

Comment: A transparent top-level window is best, but if you absolutely need to write on the screen directly, you can use `GetDC(0)` to get the `HDC` canvas handle for the screen, and then you can draw on it as needed.

Comment: Thank you. I think I'll go for the window

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you can draw directly to the screen. [GetDC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144871.aspx) offers to return the appropriate device context:

> *hWnd* [in]
>
> A handle to the window whose DC is to be retrieved. **If this value is NULL, GetDC retrieves the DC for the entire screen.**

Rendering directly to the screen poses at least two problems that need to be addressed:

1. The screen DC is a shared resource. Whenever someone else renders to the screen (e.g. when a window is displayed), that portion of the screen gets overwritten.
2. Rendering is destructive. When rendering into a device context, the original contents get overwritten. To implement a fade-out effect you would have to save the original contents (and update them dynamically as other windows are displayed).

Both issues can be solved by creating a window instead. A window is not required to have a border, caption bar, system menu or minimize/maximize/close buttons. The appropriate [Window Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600.aspx) are `WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE`.

To make the window show up in front of everything else, it needs to be marked as topmost (using the `WS_EX_TOPMOST` [Extended Window Style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543.aspx)). Note, that this places the window above all other non-topmost windows in the Z-order. You still have to fight with other topmost windows (an arms race you cannot win).

To implement transparency the window must have the `WS_EX_LAYERED` extended window style as well to create a [Layered Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#layered). Alpha transparency is then enabled calling [SetLayeredWindowAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633540.aspx). To keep the window background fully transparent regardless of the window's alpha transparency you also need to enable color keying. A simple way to do this is to set the `hbrBackground` member of the [WNDCLASSEX structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633577.aspx) to [`(HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144925.aspx), and specify `RGB(0, 0, 0)` as the `crKey` argument in the call to `SetLayeredWindowAttributes`.

---

Proof of concept (error checking elided for brevity):

```
#define STRICT 1
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
#include <windows.h>

// Forward declarations
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM );

// Entry point
int APIENTRY wWinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance,
                       HINSTANCE /*hPrevInstance*/,
                       LPTSTR    /*lpCmdLine*/,
                       int       nCmdShow ) {
```

First up is registering the main application window class. The important piece is the `hbrBackground` member. This controls background rendering, and will eventually be made fully transparent.

```
    const wchar_t k_WndClassName[] = L"OverlayWindowClass";

    // Register window class
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex = { 0 };
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof( wcex );
    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hCursor        = ::LoadCursorW( NULL, IDC_ARROW );
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)::GetStockObject( BLACK_BRUSH );
    wcex.lpszClassName  = k_WndClassName;
    ::RegisterClassExW( &wcex );
```

This is all the setup code required to instantiate a window, and adjust it's attributes. Alpha transparency is enabled to prepare for the fade-out effect, while color keying masks out those areas of the window that aren't rendered to.

```
    HWND hWnd = ::CreateWindowExW( WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_LAYERED,
                                   k_WndClassName,
                                   L"Overlay Window",
                                   WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE,
                                   CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                   800, 600,
                                   NULL, NULL,
                                   hInstance,
                                   NULL );
    // Make window semi-transparent, and mask out background color
    ::SetLayeredWindowAttributes( hWnd, RGB( 0, 0, 0 ), 128, LWA_ALPHA | LWA_COLORKEY );
```

The remainder of `wWinMain` is boilerplate windows application code.

```
    ::ShowWindow( hWnd, nCmdShow );
    ::UpdateWindow( hWnd );

    // Main message loop:
    MSG msg = { 0 };
    while ( ::GetMessageW( &msg, NULL, 0, 0 ) > 0 )
    {
        ::TranslateMessage( &msg );
        ::DispatchMessageW( &msg );
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

The window procedure is performs simple rendering. To demonstrate both alpha and key color transparency the code renders a white ellipse with the client area as the bounding rectangle. In addition, the [WM_NCHITTEST message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645618.aspx) is also handled, to provide a simple way to dragged the window accross the screen using the mouse or another pointing device. Note that mouse input is passed to the window underneath for all areas that are fully transparent.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    switch ( message )
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps = { 0 };
            HDC hDC = ::BeginPaint( hWnd, &ps );
            RECT rc = { 0 };
            ::GetClientRect( hWnd, &rc );
            HBRUSH hbrOld = (HBRUSH)::SelectObject( hDC,
                                                    ::GetStockObject( WHITE_BRUSH ) );
            ::Ellipse( hDC, rc.left, rc.top, rc.right, rc.bottom );
            ::SelectObject( hDC, hbrOld );
            ::EndPaint( hWnd, &ps );
        }
        return 0;

    case WM_NCHITTEST:
        return HTCAPTION;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        ::PostQuitMessage( 0 );
        return 0;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return ::DefWindowProc( hWnd, message, wParam, lParam );
}
```

---

Alternative `WM_PAINT` handler, that outputs text. It's important to use a text color different from the key color. If you want to use black text you will have to use a different key color.

```
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps = { 0 };
            HDC hDC = ::BeginPaint( hWnd, &ps );
            RECT rc = { 0 };
            ::GetClientRect( hWnd, &rc );
            ::SetTextColor( hDC, RGB( 255, 255, 255 ) );
            ::SetBkMode( hDC, TRANSPARENT );
            ::DrawTextExW( hDC, L"Hello, World!", -1, &rc,
                           DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER, NULL );
            ::EndPaint( hWnd, &ps );
        }
        return 0;
```

Comment: Generally this works really great. However, when I display a text with `DrawText`, the background is always white, despite the fact that the window itself is transparent. When I use `SetBkMode(hDC, TRANSPARENT)` before `DrawText`, nothing is shown. Is there a fix for that?

Comment: @divB: I assume you rendered your text using the key color (black). The key color will be replaced with whatever is underneath the window. The text will essentially appear fully transparent. I updated the answer to include code rendering text instead.

Comment: @IInspectable, is it possible to reach the same effect but without settings the "color keying"? What if I want to use all colors (thus I cannot use any color as "transparency color")? Is it possible to configure it in a way when I can specify an alpha channel value when I draw something (so I can draw the shape I need and then fill the rest of the window with a "brush" which has an alpha chnanel? or specify that the window is filled up by a transparent color by default and then draw the shape on top of it?)

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to be able to write directly to the screen (in the example it is to display the ACTUAL Windows version info). I did a lot of searching and was finally able to cobble together the code…

```
Imports System.Environment

Public Class frmMain
    Dim stringFont As Font
    Dim string_format As New StringFormat()

    Dim my_WinName As String
    Const my_WinStatic As String = " ver. "
    Dim my_WinVersion As String
    Dim my_WinRelease As String
    Dim my_WinBuild As String
    Dim my_WinSubBuild As String
    Dim my_Delim1 As String
    Dim emb_Delim1 As Boolean
    Dim my_Delim2 As String
    Dim emb_Delim2 As Boolean
    Dim txt_Display_Ver As String
    Dim txt_Curr_Build As String
    Dim txt_UBR_Value As String
    Dim the_File As String
    Dim version_Complete As Boolean
    Dim current_Ver As String
    Dim previous_Ver As String

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            If My.Settings.UpgradeRequired = True Then
                My.Settings.Upgrade()
                My.Settings.UpgradeRequired = False
                My.Settings.Save()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Upgrade from Previous Version Error")
        End Try

        conMenuAbout.Text = My.Application.Info.AssemblyName & "  (ver. " & My.Application.Info.Version.ToString & ")"
        prop_Grid.SelectedObject = My.Settings

        string_format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
        string_format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near

        version_Complete = False

        form_Defaults()

        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized

        nextTime.Interval = 500
        nextTime.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub nextTime_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles nextTime.Tick
        Dim d As Graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero)

        Dim brush_Name As System.Drawing.Brush = New System.Drawing.SolidBrush(My.Settings.color_Win_Name)
        Dim brush_Static As System.Drawing.Brush = New System.Drawing.SolidBrush(My.Settings.color_static_Ver)
        Dim brush_WinVer As System.Drawing.Brush = New System.Drawing.SolidBrush(My.Settings.color_Win_Version)
        Dim brush_CharDelim As System.Drawing.Brush = New System.Drawing.SolidBrush(My.Settings.color_Char_Delim)
        Dim brush_Curr_Rel As System.Drawing.Brush = New System.Drawing.SolidBrush(My.Settings.color_Curr_Release)
        Dim brush_Curr_Bld As System.Drawing.Brush = New System.Drawing.SolidBrush(My.Settings.color_Curr_Build)
        Dim brush_UBR_Delim As System.Drawing.Brush = New System.Drawing.SolidBrush(My.Settings.color_UBR_Delim)
        Dim brush_UBR_Rev As System.Drawing.Brush = New System.Drawing.SolidBrush(My.Settings.color_UpdateBldRev)

        update_Version()

        Dim writeHere As New PointF(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Right - 300, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Bottom - 64)
        d.DrawString(my_WinName, stringFont, brush_Name, writeHere)

        writeHere.X += d.MeasureString(my_WinName, stringFont).Width - My.Settings.Space_1
        d.DrawString(my_WinStatic, stringFont, brush_Static, writeHere)

        writeHere.X += d.MeasureString(my_WinStatic, stringFont).Width - My.Settings.Space_2
        d.DrawString(my_WinVersion, stringFont, brush_WinVer, writeHere)

        writeHere.X += d.MeasureString(my_WinVersion, stringFont).Width - My.Settings.Space_3
        d.DrawString(my_Delim1, stringFont, brush_CharDelim, writeHere)

        writeHere.X += d.MeasureString(my_Delim1, stringFont).Width - My.Settings.Space_4
        d.DrawString(my_WinRelease, stringFont, brush_Curr_Rel, writeHere)

        writeHere.X += d.MeasureString(my_WinRelease, stringFont).Width - My.Settings.Space_5
        d.DrawString(my_Delim1, stringFont, brush_CharDelim, writeHere)

        writeHere.X += d.MeasureString(my_Delim1, stringFont).Width - My.Settings.Space_6
        d.DrawString(my_WinBuild, stringFont, brush_Curr_Bld, writeHere)

        writeHere.X += d.MeasureString(my_WinBuild, stringFont).Width - My.Settings.Space_7
        d.DrawString(my_Delim2, stringFont, brush_UBR_Delim, writeHere)

        writeHere.X += d.MeasureString(my_Delim2, stringFont).Width - My.Settings.Space_8
        d.DrawString(my_WinSubBuild, stringFont, brush_UBR_Rev, writeHere)

    End Sub

    Public Sub form_Defaults()

        Try
            nextTime.Interval = My.Settings.updateInterval
            Me.Opacity = My.Settings.Opacity / 100
            my_Delim1 = My.Settings.char_Delimiter
            emb_Delim1 = My.Settings.embolden_Char_Delim
            my_Delim2 = My.Settings.UBR_Delimiter
            emb_Delim2 = My.Settings.embolden_UBR_Char
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

        update_Version()

        If current_Ver <> previous_Ver Then
            Try
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(My.Settings.text_Version_File) Then
                    the_File = My.Settings.text_Version_File
                Else
                    ofd.FileName = "WinVer.txt"
                    If ofd.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
                        My.Settings.text_Version_File = ofd.FileName
                        the_File = ofd.FileName
                    End If
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                Dim str_Err = ex.Message
                ofd.FileName = "WinVer.txt"
                If ofd.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
                    My.Settings.text_Version_File = ofd.FileName
                    the_File = ofd.FileName
                End If
            End Try
            conMenuSaveVer_Click(Nothing, Nothing)
            previous_Ver = current_Ver
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub update_Version()
        Try
            Dim tmpStr As String = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", "ProductName", Nothing)
            my_WinName = Replace(tmpStr, "Windows ", "Win ")
            tmpStr = Replace(my_WinName, "Professional", "Pro")
            my_WinName = Replace(tmpStr, "Enterprise", "Pro")
            my_WinVersion = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", "CurrentVersion", Nothing)
            my_WinRelease = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", "DisplayVersion", Nothing)
            my_WinBuild = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", "CurrentBuild", Nothing)
            Dim myKey As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryView.Registry64)
            Dim myKey2 As Object = myKey.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion")
            Dim myVal As Int64 = Convert.ToInt64(myKey2.GetValue("UBR").ToString)
            my_WinSubBuild = myVal
            current_Ver = my_WinName & my_WinVersion & my_WinRelease & my_WinBuild & my_WinSubBuild
            stringFont = New Font(My.Settings.useFont, My.Settings.useFont.Style)
            version_Complete = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub conMenuExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles conMenuExit.Click
        Application.Exit()
    End Sub

    Private Sub conMenuSettings_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles conMenuSettings.Click
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmMain_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Resize
        If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Then
            Me.sysTrayIcon.Visible = True
            Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
        Else
            Me.ShowInTaskbar = True
            Me.sysTrayIcon.Visible = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmMain_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        e.Cancel = True
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
    End Sub

    Private Sub conMenuSaveVer_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles conMenuSaveVer.Click
        If version_Complete = False Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Try
            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(the_File, current_Ver, False)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(Me, ex.Message, "Save Version Error")
        End Try

        Try
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(current_Ver) Then
                If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(current_Ver) Then
                    Clipboard.SetText(current_Ver)
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(Me, ex.Message, "Clipboard Error")
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```