# How to draw on transparent client area?

Tags: winapi, gdi, direct2d

I have a fully transparent window (I removed non client area). Now I want to draw a rectangle on it. Actually I want to draw blurred rectangle, but first I just want to understand simple things. I found that for drawing can be used following technologies:

- gdi
- gdi+
- direct2d
- directWrite

I googled and found that the modern way is to use direct2d. I'm trying to draw a rectangle and I'm getting artifacts:

- if I'm rendering a window with `SetLayeredWindowAttributes(m_hwnd, RGB(0, 0, 0), 128, LWA_ALPHA);` all my area becomes semitransparent despite the fact that my rectangle is opaque.
- if I'm using `SetLayeredWindowAttributes(m_hwnd, RGB(255, 255, 255), 128, LWA_COLORKEY);` than transparency is ignored and but window becomes mouse-inactive.

Comment: `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` supports **two** transparency modes: Alpha transparency, which can be used to implement translucent areas, and key color transparency, where pixels of a specific color are rendered fully transparent. Either way, fully transparent areas do not receive mouse/touch input. Alpha transparency is active for the entire window. The alpha channel of primitives rendered onto a window are ignored. A word on Direct2D: It's generally slower than GDI. While GDI is claimed to be deprecated, it's usually still the most appropriate infrastructure.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand this and now I can draw opaque things on fully transparent window, but only with gdi. What is the way to draw **semitransparent** shape on **fully** transparent window? Right now my rectangle with 0.5 opacity blends with window bg and not transparent (i.e. I can't see contents behind the window).

Comment: You can combine alpha and key color transparency with `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` (use `LWA_COLORKEY | LWA_ALPH`). Set your window background color (`WNDCLASSEX::hbrBackground`) to your key color, and apply an alpha value. That way your window background is fully transparent, and everything rendered with a different color becomes semi transparent.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. This almost works. Now I want to apply this techniques to gradient. Let's say I have a circle with opaque center and transparent outer ring. I can draw this gradient, but it blends with a color specified in `WNDCLASSEX::hbrBackground` but I want it to blend with transparent pixels.

Comment: `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` doesn't support per-pixel alpha. You set one value and that's that. A fully working sample implementation of the above can be found in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29100008/1889329).

Comment: Ok, but what is the way to blend per pixel with gdi?

Comment: [`AlphaBlend()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @andlabs It seems it works only for non-transparent window. With transparent window it somehow always blend with some opaque background. And it seems the only way to to do what I want is to use `UpdateLayeredWindow()`