# C++ method to display text and graphics on windows, outside the application

Tags: c++, windows, text, screen, display

I am writing an application where I need to display arbitrary images and messages on the screen (at random position), outside my application. My first try with layered windows did fail, because when I have its alfa value 0, no content can be seen either. Is any other solution for this?

Comment: Welcome to SO, you might need to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hello, thanks for the advice, I am reading. However, my problem is well defined, I don't see why this would be a bad question. So, I would like to display images and messages on the screen outside my application window.

Comment: @Brian You should show some code that adheres to [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guidelines. Otherwise we can only guess what is it that you are trying to do.

Comment: You should provide what you tried so far. So it will be easier to fix your problem (There is a specific section on one of the two link I provided you). I didn't say it was a bad question, but with code people will be more willing to help you.

Comment: Ok, I've tried two ways already, posting it ASAP, when not on my mobile.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29091028/windows-api-write-to-screen-as-on-screen-display

Comment: What OS? Windows, Linux, OS X, other? What toolkit? Gtk, Xlib, Qt, GDI, other?

Comment: @Michael Kuznetsov: Not a duplicate but almost similar problem, seems there is some useful answer there, thank you for sharing!

Comment: @Jesper: on Windows, Win32 application for best portability between Windows versions (for Linux, I have a working solution)